# running iPhone app as root

Tags: iphone, root

I am developing an iPhone app for jailbroken devices, and I need root privileges. Is there documentation for making my app run as root?

Comment: For those voting "off-topic", I believe he's asking about how his application can programmatically elevate its privileges on the iPhone, which would seem to be a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

To run any executable with root privileges it must be owned by root and it needs suid in permissions to set that you have to be logged as root in terminal:

```
# chown root your_executable
# chmod u+s  your_executable
```